# summarizing multiindex pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With the Sample, the target is:

> Compute the funtions in each value of `'A'`, in other words, compute something in all values of the variables in all `B` values in each `A` label.:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                              'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                       'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                              'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                       'C' : np.random.randn(8),
                       'D' : np.random.randn(8)})

def var1(x): return max(x)-min(x)
def var2(x): return (max(x)-min(x))/max(x)
def var3(x): return (max(x)-min(x))/ len(x)

df = df.groupby(['A','B']).agg({'C': var1, 'D': [var2, var3]})
```

[image: output]

## Target

The Output would look like this:

```
A           var1        var2        var3        
bar         0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000
foo         1,008986    -0.8572265  0.3015905
```

functions like:

```
def var1(x): return max(x)-min(x)
def var2(x): return (max(x)-min(x))/max(x)
def var3(x): return (max(x)-min(x))/ len(x)
def mean(numbers):
    return float(sum(numbers)) / max(len(numbers), 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
                  C         D
               var1      var2      var3
A   B
bar one    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
    three  0.000000 -0.000000  0.000000
    two    0.000000 -0.000000  0.000000
foo one    1.585287  0.663121  0.101220
    three  0.000000 -0.000000  0.000000
    two    0.799511 -0.074874  0.032681

In [9]: df.mean(level='A')
Out[9]:
            C         D
         var1      var2      var3
A
bar  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
foo  0.794933  0.196082  0.044634
```

or using custom function:

```
In [12]: def f(col):
    ...:     return np.mean(col) ** 2
    ...:

In [13]: df.groupby(level='A').apply(f)
Out[13]:
            C         D
         var1      var2      var3
A
bar  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
foo  0.631918  0.038448  0.001992
```